# Optimizing run time in Double Linked LIst

Tags: java, performance, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So I have a method which supposes to insert the data at the given index in the linked list.  A method which I have implemented does exactly that it passes JUnit tests for functionalities and corrections.
However, it does not pass time efficiency test in JUnit.

My logic to solve this problem is finding out where exactly index is.
For example, I can do if an index is <= (size/2) then start traversing at the head of the linked list. Otherwise, start at the point which equals (size/2) and continues till index is found.
Not sure this logic is one of the correct ways to solve time efficiency.

How do I go about and make this method concise and efficient?

```
   public T removeAtIndex(int index) {

    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    LinkedListNode<T> temp = head;
   int i = 0;
    if (index == 0) {
        return removeFromFront();
    }
    if (index == size - 1) {
        return removeFromBack();
    }
    while (i < index) {
        temp = temp.getNext();
        i++;
    }
    temp.getPrevious().setNext(temp.getNext());
    temp.getNext().setPrevious(temp.getPrevious());
    size--;
    return temp.getData();
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can so how to implement that logic.

Comment: *Otherwise, start at the point which equals (size/2)*: that is not possible: you don't have a reference to the middle element of the list. Only to the first one and the last one. So you can start from the front and go forward if index is in the first half, or start from the end and go backwards if index is in the second half. Just to be sure: you know that Java has a standard LinkedList class, and that an ArrayList is pretty much always faster anyway, right?

Comment: Correct, that was my way to approach. I could not think of anything else at the moment.

Comment: Just don't do it. Linked list is hopeless w.r.t. performance. There are only very few cases when it makes sense and all of them AFAIK are related to multithreading. Pretty always, `ArrayList` wins hands down.

Comment: I guess the simple answer is that removing an element from a linked list is always O(n) and it can't be better no matter what do you do in your code.

Comment: You generally shouldn't be referring to nodes through indices. If you have a reference to the node, you could remove it in constant-time, not linear-time. Otherwise it's inevitably a linear-time operation as others pointed out.